# ADF connectivity to Azure SQL Database with AD Universal/MFA

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Customer has just implemented a new Azure SQL Database instance. They are using the 'Azure Active Directory Universal with MFA' (multi-factor authentication) security option. I am trying to connect to this database through Azure Data Factory, and nothing works. I've tried all 3 connection string variations, and I'm beginning to think programmatic access is not possible.

Has anyone run into this, and were you successful in connecting? If so, please elaborate -- I expect a lot more of us are going to start seeing this in our work.

Comment: Use Service Principal or Managed Identity?

Comment: Managed Identity is set up properly, but the system is still throwing an error. I am still trying to configure the Service Principal for authentication, but for the life of me I can't find the application key that they're asking for -- the "Service Principal Key" is what it is asking for. Anyone have any idea what value they're asking for, and where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to configure Azure SQL Database Linked Service in ADF using service principal.

1. Go to `Azure Active Directory` in Azure Portal and click on `App registration`  under Manage on left side options. Click on `+ New registration`.

[image]

2. In new app registration page, just give `Name` to your app and click on `register`.

[image]

3. Once the app created, copy the, `Application ID` and paste it under `Service principal ID` in Linked Service. The `tenant ID` must be already there in Linked service. If not, you can copy that also and paste under `Tenant` in Linked Service.

[image]

4. For `service principal key`, you need to create the Secret for newly registered app. Go to `Certificates and secret` in new app, and click on `+ New  client secret`. Once created, copy the `Value` of the secret as shown below. Copy this `Value` under `service principal key` in Linked Service.

[image]

5. Now, before checking `test connection`, you need to set the registered app as server admin in SQL Server. Go to SQL Server, click on `Azure Active Directory` on left side. Click on `Set admin` option, search for the name of the app you have created above. Select the app. Click on `Save` option.

[image]

6. At last, just check your connection in Linked Service. It should work fine now. Refer below image.

[image]

Comment: If anyone need the connection string for Azure Data Factory to use AD service principal (I was looking for it too): it is `Data Source=SERVER_NAME.database.windows.net;Initial catalog=DB_NAME;Integrated security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection timeout=30;`