# Migrate encrypted data to Azure Sql using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have an Azure container that has daily data backup files which are .bak database files and we want to load data into our Azure SQL database but there are some encrypted columns of tables in the .bak file and every time when we try to insert the data from a container to Azure SQL database using data factory it gives
Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider.

Is there a way to decrypt the columns before loading the data using the Data factory?

Answer (score 0):

Generally we use `Always Encrypted` feature to keep the sensitive data safe while restoring database.

For error - **Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider** - You need to check the permission on Key which is required to decrypt the data.

- Go to `Key Vault` and select `Access Policies` on the left side
- Click on `Add new` button on the top
- Select `Service Principal` which you are using to access the data (App registered in Azure Active Directory which is used to access the resources)
- From the Key permissions drop down, make sure you give it "Decrypt", "Sign", "Get", "UnwrapKey" permissions
- `Save` the changes

Now try to run the ADF pipeline and this should work properly.

To check how to use App registration service principal ID, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73228102/adf-connectivity-to-azure-sql-database-with-ad-universal-mfa/73305053#73305053).

Comment: we tried all these before the thing is we have our encryption certificate stored in a key vault and the problem I think or what I believe is the ADF cannot be able to access the.pfx certificate which we have in Azure key vault.